# Change selection mode in Windows command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line

Is there a way to change the selection mode of the Windows command prompt from block selection to regular selection?

Comment: What do you mean for "regular selection"? Like the one of most terminals in Linux? As far as I know, it's not available in the Windows console.

Comment: I would really like this too.

Answer (score 1):

Properties -> Options -> tick "QuickEdit Mode".

You might want to do the same in Defaults so it's like that every time.

Comment: This is about as close as you'll get...

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Still block selection

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, just check **Enable line wrapping selection**:

[image: Screenshot of cmd.exe Properties dialog]